# Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP

Tags: homebrew

Each time I run a `brew` command on the terminal, I continuously get this message:

```
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

I've already set the variable `export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP=TRUE` in `~/.zshrc`.

Should `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP` be set to `false`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is your shell problem, `export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP=TRUE` works for me in both terminal session as well as `~/.bash_profile` (I am using bash).

You can validate your default shel by `echo $SHELL`.